# Cassandra failure during read query at consistency QUORUM - ReadFailureException

Tags: java, scala, cassandra

I have a simple scala/java program to demo Cassandra java API.

I have a simple UDT class Address which is used in class User. For some reason userMapper.get(userId) fails with no clear error message.
Code is part of scala project.

Runner code (java):

```
void exp02() {
    log.debug("JAVA -- exp02");
    Cluster cluster = null;
    try {
        CodecRegistry codecRegistry = new CodecRegistry();

        cluster = Cluster.builder()                                                    // (1)
                .withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry)
                .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
                .build();

        log.debug("connect...exp02");
        Session session = cluster.connect();                                           // (2)

        MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(session);
        Mapper<User> userMapper = manager.mapper(User.class);

        // For some reason this will break
        {
            log.debug("create user *********************** isClosed: " + cluster.isClosed());

            log.debug("get users");

            ResultSet results = session.execute("SELECT * FROM cTest.user;");
            Result<User> user = userMapper.map(results);
            for (User u : user) {
                log.debug("User : " + u);
            }
            log.debug("Users printed");

            UUID userId = UUID.fromString("567378a9-8533-4d1c-80a8-71bf4b77189e");
            User u2 = userMapper.get(userId); // <<<--- This line throws exception, (JRunner.java:67)
            log.debug("Select user = " +  u2);

        }

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        log.error("Exception: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        log.debug("close...exp02");
        if (cluster != null) cluster.close();                                          // (5)
    }
}
```

Main (scala):

```
package com.example.crunner

import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}

object MainRunner {
  val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass())
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val jrunner = new JRunner()
    jrunner.exp02()
  }
}
```

User class (java):

```
package com.example.crunner;

import java.util.UUID;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Column;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.PartitionKey;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Table;

@Table(keyspace = "cTest", name = "user",
        readConsistency = "QUORUM",
        writeConsistency = "QUORUM"
//        caseSensitiveKeyspace = false,
//        caseSensitiveTable = false
)
public class User {
    @PartitionKey
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private UUID userId;
    private String name;
    private Address address;

    public User(UUID userId, String name, Address address) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public User() { address = new Address(); }
    public UUID getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(UUID userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "userId=" + userId +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", address=" + address +
                '}';
    }
}
```

UDT Address class (java)

```
package com.example.crunner;

import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Field;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.UDT;

@UDT(keyspace = "cTest", name = "addressT") //, caseSensitiveType = true)
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private int zipCode;

    public Address(String street, int zipCode) {
        this.street = street;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public Address() {
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
    public int getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }
    public void setZipCode(int zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address{" +
                "street='" + street + '\'' +
                ", zipCode=" + zipCode +
                '}';
    }

}
```

CQL (other tables not included here):

```
CREATE TYPE ctest.addresst (
    street text,
    zipcode int
);


CREATE TABLE ctest.user (
    user_id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    address addresst,
    name text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

build.sbt

```
name := "CassJExp2"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.9"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

val cassandraVersion = "3.2.0"
val logbackVersion = "1.2.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % logbackVersion withSources() withJavadoc(), //
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % logbackVersion withSources() withJavadoc(), //
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-access" % logbackVersion withSources() withJavadoc(), //
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.25" withSources() withJavadoc(), //
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.9" withSources() withJavadoc(), //

  "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % cassandraVersion withSources() withJavadoc(), //
  "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-mapping" % cassandraVersion withSources() withJavadoc(), //
  "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-extras" % cassandraVersion withSources() withJavadoc() //
)

scalacOptions += "-deprecation"
```

When I run this code on sbt console, I get following output:

```
18:08:41.447 [run-main-f] DEBUG com.example.crunner.JRunner - JAVA -- exp02
18:08:41.497 [run-main-f] INFO  c.d.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility - Detected Guava >= 19 in the classpath, using modern compatibility layer
18:08:41.634 [run-main-f] INFO  c.datastax.driver.core.ClockFactory - Using native clock to generate timestamps.
18:08:41.644 [run-main-f] DEBUG com.example.crunner.JRunner - connect...exp02
18:08:41.674 [run-main-f] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil - Did not find Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, defaulting to NIO.
18:08:42.049 [run-main-f] INFO  c.d.d.c.p.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy - Using data-center name 'datacenter1' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct datacenter name with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy constructor)
18:08:42.051 [run-main-f] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - New Cassandra host /127.0.0.1:9042 added
18:08:42.107 [run-main-f] DEBUG com.example.crunner.JRunner - create user *********************** isClosed: false
18:08:42.108 [run-main-f] DEBUG com.example.crunner.JRunner - get users
18:08:42.139 [run-main-f] DEBUG com.example.crunner.JRunner - User : User{userId=54cbad6e-3f27-4b7e-bce0-8a4a4fbffbdf, name='John Doe', address=Address{street='street', zipCode=512}}
18:08:42.139 [run-main-f] DEBUG com.example.crunner.JRunner - User : User{userId=6122b896-8b28-448d-ac5c-4bc9b5c7c7ab, name='John Doe', address=Address{street='street', zipCode=512}}
 ... output truncated here, table contains about 150 rows ...
18:08:42.175 [run-main-f] DEBUG com.example.crunner.JRunner - User : User{userId=44f69277-ff97-4ba2-9216-bdf65eccd7c3, name='John Doe', address=Address{street='street', zipCode=512}}
18:08:42.175 [run-main-f] DEBUG com.example.crunner.JRunner - Users printed
18:08:42.203 [run-main-f] ERROR com.example.crunner.JRunner - Exception: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency QUORUM (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency QUORUM (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:130)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:30)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:41)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.get(Mapper.java:435)
    at com.example.crunner.JRunner.exp02(JRunner.java:67)
    at com.example.crunner.MainRunner$.main(MainRunner.scala:18)
    at com.example.crunner.MainRunner.main(MainRunner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:67)
    at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:61)
    at sbt.Run.sbt$Run$$execute$1(Run.scala:51)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Logger$$anon$4.apply(Logger.scala:84)
    at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:248)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency QUORUM (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:142)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:140)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:179)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2400(RequestHandler.java:49)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:799)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:633)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1075)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:998)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency QUORUM (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:88)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:38)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:289)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:269)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
    ... 20 more
18:08:42.205 [run-main-f] DEBUG com.example.crunner.JRunner - close...exp02
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Apr 18, 2017 6:08:45 PM
```

At the same time I get the following error message into /var/log/cassandra/system.log:

```
WARN  [ReadStage-2] 2017-04-18 18:08:42,202 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[ReadStage-2,10,main]: {}
java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.BTreeRow.getCell(BTreeRow.java:212) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SinglePartitionReadCommand.canRemoveRow(SinglePartitionReadCommand.java:895) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SinglePartitionReadCommand.reduceFilter(SinglePartitionReadCommand.java:859) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SinglePartitionReadCommand.queryMemtableAndSSTablesInTimestampOrder(SinglePartitionReadCommand.java:744) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SinglePartitionReadCommand.queryMemtableAndDiskInternal(SinglePartitionReadCommand.java:515) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SinglePartitionReadCommand.queryMemtableAndDisk(SinglePartitionReadCommand.java:492) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SinglePartitionReadCommand.queryStorage(SinglePartitionReadCommand.java:358) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommand.executeLocally(ReadCommand.java:397) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$LocalReadRunnable.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1801) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2486) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:136) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:109) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

Cassandra version is [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.9 | CQL spec 3.4.2 | Native protocol v4]

So userMapper can map ResultSet of users but getting a single user will fail. The userId I try to fetch exists in the user table. It is also possible to save a new user into db using the userMapper without failure.

I don't know if this is somehow related to having a UDT Address in User class. Tables / mappers without UDT classes are working fine.

EDIT:

As Marko Švaljek suggested I tried the query at command line:

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM cTest.user where user_id=567378a9-8533-4d1c-80a8-71bf4b77189e;
ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

Looks like same error than with java client.

SELECT * FROM cTest.user works fine.

EDIT 2:

This is single instance environment.

```
nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  354.4 KiB  256          ?       33490146-da36-4359-bb24-42854bdb3c26  rack1

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

What's the reason for this error and how to fix it? Thank you for your support.

Comment: To be honest this might be a bug in cassandra. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/8qxErYiRNMg Just of of curiosity, what happens when you do requests at CL - One? Also did you have any cassandra upgrades of sstables?

Comment: MS: See edit above. What you mean by cassandra upgrades of sstables?

Comment: Basically if you had data in some earlier version of cassandra and then when you upgraded you probably also upgraded the sstables. According to earlier provided info this might be a bug in cassandra 3.9 actually. If you have option I would recommend restoring older version of cassandra and trying the same querry out. One more question how are you running cassandra is it single instance or is there multiple? can you also provide `nodetool status` result

Comment: I haven't upgraded cassandra, so the keyspace (and tables) was initially created into this version 3.9.

Comment: This actually all looks normal. I also checked cassandra source code. Would it be possible to drop all the data and recreate from scratch ... there is something weird going on there :)

Comment: This is demo environment where I'm experimenting various things. I have dropped those tables several times. I think I had this same problem earlier (but did not concentrate this error on that time) and when I recreated tables, the problem went away. So probably it works also this time. This time I wanted to check what is causing this error and therefore not just recreate tables. If this is cassandra error, can it be that some other changes in db schema can cause User table query fail although those "other changes" are not related to User table or Address type?

Comment: If you are willing to invest time you would have to pin point scenarios how it comes to this situation. This is looks like a bug in cassandra, but to officially report it you would need to prepare some scenarios with detailed description how you got there.

Comment: I dropped User table and created it again and now everything works without failure. Could it be that this probable error is related to tables having UDTs or is it just coincidence?

Comment: It might be, it's hard to tell from what I can tell in the cassandra code the cell information just got corrupted somehow, but it would take me really a lot of time to pin point it :) so I guess it's better to leave it to people that do it for a living.